# Finding by ID in postgresql very slow on big table

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2, heroku

I have videos table with 18M rows. When I search for particular video by ID, it takes up to 6 seconds to complete. Sometimes it takes few milliseconds, sometimes up to 6 seconds, but on average it is around 2 seconds.

Application is hosted on heroku and I'm using Crane database (https://addons.heroku.com/heroku-postgresql) with 410MB of RAM.

Is there any way to speed this up? I'm querying for videos 50 times per second on average, and new videos are inserted/updated at rate of 50 per second.

```
explain analyze SELECT * FROM videos WHERE id = 17841464 LIMIT 1;
                                                            QUERY PLAN                                                            
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=0.00..6.43 rows=1 width=119) (actual time=2337.892..2337.894 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Index Scan using videos_pkey on videos  (cost=0.00..6.43 rows=1 width=119) (actual time=2337.888..2337.888 rows=1 loops=1)
         Index Cond: (id = 17841464)
 Total runtime: 2337.943 ms
```

Here is how the table looks like:

```
 \d+ videos;
                                                           Table "public.videos"
     Column     |            Type             |                      Modifiers                      | Storage  | Stats target | Description 
----------------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------+----------+--------------+-------------
 id             | integer                     | not null default nextval('videos_id_seq'::regclass) | plain    |              | 
 uuid           | character(11)               | not null                                            | extended |              | 
 channel_id     | integer                     | not null                                            | plain    |              | 
 category_id    | integer                     |                                                     | plain    |              | 
 title          | character varying(255)      |                                                     | extended |              | 
 published_at   | timestamp without time zone |                                                     | plain    |              | 
 view_count     | bigint                      |                                                     | plain    |              | 
 like_count     | integer                     |                                                     | plain    |              | 
 dislike_count  | integer                     |                                                     | plain    |              | 
 favorite_count | integer                     |                                                     | plain    |              | 
 comment_count  | integer                     |                                                     | plain    |              | 
 disabled       | boolean                     | default false                                       | plain    |              | 
 created_at     | timestamp without time zone |                                                     | plain    |              | 
 updated_at     | timestamp without time zone |                                                     | plain    |              | 
Indexes:
    "videos_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "videos_uuid_idx" UNIQUE, btree (uuid)
    "videos_latest_by_channel_idx" btree (channel_id, published_at DESC)
    "videos_top_by_channel_idx" btree (channel_id, view_count DESC)
Has OIDs: no
```

Comment: An index scan shouldn't take that long. That sounds like a hardware problem. (Btw: there is need to specify `LIMIT 1` when you restrict the select to a single PK value)

Comment: It is also possible that your index or the table is bloated.  What does `\di+ videos_pkey` show as size?

Comment: @dezso could that happen due to many updates of the "count" columns? And would it make sense to move those columns into a separate table?

Comment: @ypercube Yes, as the other columns look rather static, this can be a good idea.  Probably the `counts` table could be moved to a smaller and faster disk as well.  And I find the `view_count` bigint a rather optimistic type choice :)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name .. probably meant to write *no* need for `LIMIT 1`.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter: yes, absolutely.

Comment: Thanks guys. `videos_pkey` size is: 934 MB. Row data (title, counts, .. etc) is updated once per day. These are youtube videos being synced on daily basis and yes some of them are most likely to exceed INTEGER ranges in near future.

Comment: I have copied entire database locally and it runs very fast. This is probably related to overloading the database with 50 concurrent connections each hitting several queries per second. Can you suggest me some database-as-a-service that is able to handle this kind of load?

Comment: also, do you think i would benefit in speed if i convert title to CHAR instead of VARCHAR?

Comment: May be the load of the database is very high, see "top -c"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Honestly I have never seen a single value btree lookup take this long.  I don't think your problem is simply in your query.  I think it is elsewhere.

First you say you have a lot of writes.  This probably means you are constantly pushing a lot of stuff out of the buffers and doing a lot of random disk I/O.  I would not be surprised if a lot of the bottleneck is in the general I/O and your lack of RAM.

For 18 million rows, these don't look very large.  They may all fit in memory.

At any rate the first thing to do if had access to the command line on the server would be to take CPU I/O wait vs user vs system time (you may be able to do that elsewhere in your code).  Also run explain with (ANALYSE, BUFFERS, VERBOSE) set so that you can see much more about what is going on.  These should give you an idea if your problem is underwhelming CPU activity, slow RAM, or lots of disk I/O but as it is, there is very little that can be done.

Another thing you can do is this:

```
VACUUM ANALYSE VERBOSE;
```

See if that speeds things up.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It turned out to be the disk I/O issue (due to millions reads/writes) and insufficient RAM. The other issue was the load itself (tens of concurrent connections with hundreds of read/write queries per second). I decited to migrate the "big hot part" of the database to DynamoDB and leave everything else. As a result, everything went back to normal with queries faster up to 50 times. Thanks for your help

Comment: What about 500+ million rows? Is `btree (id)` relaible in this case? Or should we use databases like Cassandra, unQLite?